# Ionic build on iOS returns "BUILD FAILED"

Tags: ios, macos, cordova, ionic-framework

I'm working on Ionic on a Mac machine. I have installed Google Analytics plugin and trying to build project but it is not working.

I am getting following error:

```
** **BUILD FAILED** **


The following build commands failed:
    ..../path normal i386

(1 failure)

>Error: Error code 65 for command: xcodebuild with args:
-xcconfig,/Volumes/Workspace/Dev/TestApp/platforms/ios/cordova/build-debug.xcconfig,
-project,TestApp.xcodeproj,
-target,TestApp,-configuration,Debug,-sdk,iphonesimulator,-destination,platform=iOS Simulator,build,CONFIGURATION_BUILD_DIR=/Volumes/Workspace/Dev/TestApp/platforms/ios/build/emulator,SHARED_PRECOMPS_DIR=/Volumes/Workspace/Dev/TestApp/platforms/ios/build/sharedpch
```

I have tried with platform removing and add adding but still not got fixed.

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Is that all the information that you get in terminal?  It looks like there is information missing, particularly an error message?

Answer (score 0):

It was an issue due to xcode compatibility of plugin. uninstalling current xcode and installing xcode 7.3.1 solved issue.

**Note:** It is due to ionic build ios command internally uses xcode command to build project.